# Build protobuf with bazel error: repeated_composite_container.cc(267) fatal error C1057

Tags: visual-c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build TensorFlow with Bazel on Windows.

But i'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: C:/users/spenh/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_spen/icnq02mb/external/protobuf/BUILD:623:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:python/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so' failed: msvc_cl.bat failed: error executing command external/local_config_cc/wrapper/bin/msvc_cl.bat /DOS_WINDOWS=OS_WINDOWS /DCOMPILER_MSVC /DNOGDI /DNOMINMAX /DPRAGMA_SUPPORTED /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ... (remaining 42 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 2.
C:\users\spenh\appdata\local\temp\_bazel_spen\icnq02mb\execroot\org_tensorflow\external\protobuf\python\google\protobuf\pyext\repeated_composite_container.cc(267): fatal error C1057: Unerwartetes Dateiende bei der Erweiterung eines Makros
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Any idea what i can try to solve this? Or what information i could provide you to solve this?

- Bazel: git/master (13.06.2017)
- TensorFlow: v1.2.0-rc2
- Python 3.6.1 x64
- Visual Studio 2017 v15.0.26430.6 x64
- Java JDK 1.8.0_60
- Windows 10

Build command:

```
bazel build -c opt --cpu=x64_windows_msvc --host_cpu=x64_windows_msvc --copt=-w --host_copt=-w tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: This looks like a simple compilation error in repeated_scalar_container.cc.  Can you try a different version of TF?

Comment: I need this pull request included: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/10158 this is why i'm using the tensorflow git head.

Comment: There is no guarantee when building at HEAD.Can you open an issue on the TensorFlow issue tracker if compilation fails?

Comment: @Steren: I did (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10357) but it was closed because they think it has nothing to do with TensorFlow.